# How do I make an image button that opens a new XML page in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, onclick

Hi im trying to create a simple android app using the Eclipse IDE, all I need is a start up page with a few pages of information. Ive created a few xml pages with my desired layout and im wondering how to create an onclick event from an image button that opens another xml page? Im assuming I will have to implement an onClickListener but im new to android, is there a simple way of implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Layout (XML) add `android:onClick="goPage2"`, for example:

```
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/page2"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:onClick="goPage2"
  android:text="Go Page 2" />
```

and then in your Activity, create a method:

```
 public void goPage2(View v)
 {
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Page2Activity.class);
   startActivity(myIntent);
 }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, ive got two xml pages currently, as well as a single activity, do i need an activity for each xml page? Also do I need to create the page2Activity.class?

Comment: Hi, yes.. You need to create 2 activities because Android doesn't allow to call setContentLayout twice (or more). so basically you assign each of your xml pages to one activity.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this... either use a setOnClickListener for button in code OR the easier way is to mention the onclick property in your layout xml. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)